# Does media query "handheld" include tablets?

Tags: media-queries, tablet, handheld

This question is simple:
Does media query "handheld" include tablets?
**Note**: *I am aware that there are some devices, like iPhones, that do not use the media handheld.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://cssmediaqueries.com/what-are-css-media-queries.html

handheld : 
Used for handheld devices (Smartphones and tablets do NOT listen to this!).

Comment: What the hell is considered a handheld, then? Would you happen to know what media type speaks specifically to tablets, if any?

Comment: Check out this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile